# What happens when type-casting a pointer "sideways" in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm not that experienced with C++, but trying to learn.

The following example consists of a hierarchy of classes which are "related":

- **Child** is a child of both **Parent1** and **Parent2**
- **Parent2** is a child of **VirtualGrandParent**.
- **Parent2** contains a member **Sister* m_sister** which is a pointer to another user-defined object type. This is initialized and allocated memory with keyword *new* in Parent2's constructor. At some point in the execution this pointer is set to 0.

MainClass.cpp:

```
#include "WorkerClass.h"
using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
  WorkerClass worker;

  worker.initialize();
  worker.setProperty1();
  worker.setProperty2();
// At this point m_sister (in Parent2) is set to 0x0, which makes the next method call fail (Segmentation fault). What happens?

  worker.setAuntValue();

  return 0;
}
```

WorkerClass.h:

```
#include <map>
#include "Child.h"

class WorkerClass
{
public:
    void initialize()
    {
        Child* child1 = new Child();
        m_myMap[0] = child1;
    }

    void setProperty1()
    {
        VirtualGrandParent* ptr = m_myMap[0];
        ((Parent1*) ptr)->setProperty1(6.0);
    }

    void setProperty2()
    {
        VirtualGrandParent* ptr = m_myMap[0];
        ((Parent1*) ptr)->setProperty2(7.0);
    }

    void setAuntValue()
    {
        VirtualGrandParent* ptr = m_myMap[0];
        ((Child*) ptr)->setSisterValue(170.0);
    }

private:
    map<int, VirtualGrandParent*> m_myMap;
};
```

Child.h

```
#include "Parent1.h"
#include "Parent2.h"

class Child : public Parent1, public Parent2
{
public:
    Child(): Parent1(), Parent2() {}
    ~Child(){};
};
```

Parent1.h:

```
class Parent1
{
public:

    Parent1(): m_value1(0.0), m_value2(0.0) {}
    virtual ~Parent1() {};

    void setProperty1(double val) {m_value1=val;}
    void setProperty2(double val) {m_value2=val;}

private:
    double m_value1;
    double m_value2;
};
```

Parent2.h:

```
#include "Sister.h"
#include "VirtualGrandParent.h"

class Parent2 : public VirtualGrandParent
{
public:
    Parent2(): VirtualGrandParent() {m_sister = new Sister();}
    ~Parent2(){};

    void setSisterValue(double val){m_sister->setValue(val);}

protected:
    Sister* m_sister;
};
```

Sister.h:

```
class Sister {
public:
    Sister(): m_sisterVal(0.0) {};

    void setValue(double val)
    {
        m_sisterVal=val;
    }
private:
    double m_sisterVal;
};
```

VirtualGrandParent.h:

```
class VirtualGrandParent
{
public:
    VirtualGrandParent() {}
    virtual ~VirtualGrandParent(){};
};
```

**Question 1**: So my main question is what happens during the "sideways" casting from VirtualGrandParent to Parent1? Why is m_sister 0? Is memory overwritten?
Why does it take *two* method calls before m_sister is 0?

**Question 2**: What happens if taking the *address to the* pointer ptr in WorkerClass.h, and then cast it to a `Parent1*` pointer (example below)? Executing the code with this change results in m_sister not being set to 0. I assume this is just a coincidence? (I guess a pointer-to-pointer really should be of type `Parent1**` ?)

```
void setProperty1()
{
    VirtualGrandParent* ptr = m_myMap[0];
    ((Parent1*) &ptr)->setProperty1(6.0);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you reformulate the question, and actually add a complete example to show the problem. None of us here have your code to figure out what your vague descriptions mean exactly.

Comment: Ok, I tried to provide an example now. Hopefully this makes more sense. When I run this example I get the segmentation fault (null pointer).

Comment: This really is the best [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the problem?

Comment: It reproduces the problem... Is it to big? I can try to remove some stuff and see I still get the same error...

Comment: That may be for the best. The process itself may in fact enlighten you to the problem. The less clutter is present, the easier it is to understand.

Comment: I've stripped the example and tried to clarify the question. Hope this is better... :)

Comment: `VirtualGrandParent` contains a virtual destructor and a pointer (`m_sister`), while `Parent1` contains a virtual destructor and two doubles. So when you interpret an instance of the former as one of the latter, your pointer `m_sister` is at the position where you assume the first double to be, so when writing to that double you actually change the pointer.

Comment: So what happens here is that when casting directly from `VirtualGrandParent` to `Parent1` the object is "treated" as one containing member `m_sister`, not as a `Parent1` object?  When calling `setProperty1` to change `m_value1`, what is really changed is the memory holding `m_sister` and not the memory holding `m_value1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if we view the parentage as a tree:

```
VirtualGrandParent
       \
      Parent2        Parent1
            \       /
              Child
```

Then we can see that Parent1 and VirtualGrandParent are on different branches. So when you cast `VirtualGrandParent* ptr` to `Parent1` you aren't properly casting up or down the hierarchy. Instead that's casting across it which ends up casting between unrelated classes - and that's why it yields invalid results.

For casting along an inheritance hierarchy, try to always use at least `static_cast` (or `dynamic_cast` if desired). With a `static_cast` the compiler will validate that the cast is at least possible and otherwise give an error. In your case it should show an error.

The proper cast would be `static_cast<Parent1*>(static_cast<Child*>(ptr))`

As for your second question about `&ptr`... casting a pointer-to-a-pointer as a pointer-to-a-class is simply nonsense. If it appears work at all, that's the unfortunate luck of undefined behavior. (And it's probably not actually working correctly, but instead interpreting some arbitrary memory as if it was your class, which then happens to have a non-zero value where somePtr would be but isn't valid in any way.)

Comment: I tried your solution using `static_cast<Parent1*>(static_cast<Child*>(ptr))->setProperty1(6.0);` and it works now; Parent2's pointer is not set to 0 anymore. So _it is_ actually possible casting from VirtualGrandParent to Parent1, but it has do be done in **two** steps (from VirtualGrandParent to Child, then from Child to Parent1) and it has to be done using `static_cast`?

Comment: @Hippo Two steps, yes. Think of it like: casting along inheritance can only go either up or down the tree at a time, not up and down all in one step. Strictly speaking `static_cast` isn't required. You can use a normal C-style cast. But a C-style cast can do _anything_ - including stuff that doesn't make sense. Using `static_cast` or the other C++ style casts where appropriate helps prevent mistakes.